# Series with parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find all value of $\alpha$ when series is convergent?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(1 - \sin{\frac{\pi n^2}{2n^2 +1}}\Big)^{\alpha}$$

Could you give me tips how to solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_n$ be the general term of the series.

we have

$$u_n=(1-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2(2n^2+1)}))^\alpha$$

or

$$=(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2(2n^2+1)}))^\alpha$$

and using $$1-\cos(X) \sim \frac{X^2}{2}\;\; (X\to 0)$$ we get

$$u_n\sim  ( \frac{\pi^2}{32n^4})^\alpha\;\; (n\to+\infty)$$

thus $\; \sum u_n\;$converges $\iff \alpha>\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$1-\sin\frac{\pi n^2}{2n^2+1} = 1-\cos\frac{\pi}{4n^2+2}=2\sin^2\frac{\pi}{8n^2+4}$$
for large values of $n$ behaves like $\frac{\pi^2}{32 n^4}$, and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{32n^4}\right)^{\alpha} $$
is convergent as soon as $4\alpha>1$, i.e. as soon as $\color{red}{\alpha>\frac{1}{4}}$.